# Php csv line break in cell

Tags: php, csv, carriage-return

How do I line break in a cell in csv correctly, I tried this:

```
"\"$value\n\"";
```

This break the data in the cell but gives me an additional

```
"
```

Sign at the second data on the cell

I tried various things but could not break it and remove the

```
"
```

sign.

Does anyone have a solution

EDIT:

Current output in the csv cell is something like this:

```
value1, value2, value3....
```

What I want is something like this

```
value1,
value2,
value3
```

Comment: Can you give us what is the current output, and what is the expected output please ?

Comment: It probably makes sense if you post the core part of your csv generating code.

Comment: To start with, use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than this homebrew

Answer (score 1):

You have to add 1 more `double qoute`

```
"\"".$value."\n".$value2."\""
```

Comment: This cannot make any difference, since it results in exactly the same string.

Comment: i also had the same problem with the op a long time ago and this what was it made me put a line break inside a cell.

Comment: With the changes you now made to your code when editing your answer things get more confusing. Still: using `"\"".$value."\""` or `"\"$value\""` comes out _exactly_ the same. This is `php`, it is not a guessing game. but since you claim this solved a similar issue for you, maybe you could elaborate the difference it should make? So _why_ you claim this comes out different?

Comment: I wrote "\""$value."\n"; thats correct right?

Comment: @arkascha `"\""` adds an extra `double quote` in the value for the cell.  creating a "\n" will create a next line.  but when enclosed with `double quotes` it will just break the line inside the cell.

Comment: I changed to "\"".$value."\n"; but does not work

Comment: from my example above.  `$value` and `$value2`  will be in one cell but separated by a line break;

Comment: @roullie Though the first two points of your statement are correct (obviously), your conclusion is just wrong. We are talking about a string here that is created. That is not a magical thing that behaves different when later being placed in some file. The resulting string is _exactly_ the same, whether you use your notation with additional concatenation or without. Your version is slower, but it does notchange how string creation works in php. I suggest you create a primitive test script yourself and give it a try.

Comment: @arkascha and your point is?

Comment: @roullie As mentioned initially: your answer is nonsense. It does not change anything to create the string in the variant you suggest. That simply is not the point here.

Comment: it does answer the op's question.

Comment: Nope, it does not. The OP already did insert a line break and he did enclose the content in double quotes. Your answer does the same, you only use a different notation. But let's stop this, it's not worth discussing any further. Have fun!